# Feature request: Timer presentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Here and there, timers apply in connection with editing. As editing can require extensive research in parallel, a presentation of still left time would be very helpful. This would prevent well-elaborated comments from being refused and prevent the frustration because of the refusal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only comments are on a timer. Remember, comments are meant to be ephemeral and temporary. If you are performing "extensive research," you should probably be summarizing that research in an answer, not a comment. Answers can be edited for days or weeks – or even months or years.

Comment: "comments are meant to be ephemeral and temporary", but in reality they're often more than that. I see often comments containing crucial information, which could be answers (if we disregard their form). I wonder why it is like that but it teaches me somehow not to be too quick with posting answers and to provide research results in comments. As if someone was to take all the valueable comments some day, to compile them and to present a community answer... Well, I'm still a newbie here. And your answer teaches me to change my approach. Thanks.